# Australia: Can there be two contemporary applications for two visas of different types for different periods?

Tags: visa, australia

As a follow-up of [this](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/10672/11563) question, I'm proceeding with the application for a "Temporary activity visa (subclass 408)", in order to stay in Australia for circa six months from October 2017 to March 2018.

However, I recently have been accepted to present a paper to a conference that will be held in Australia as well, from 19th to 24th of August. Since I'm an Italian citizen, I applied for an "eVisitor (subclass 651)".

The question is the following: will having an eVisitor for the August trip impact in any way the application for the "Temporary activity" visa that I'm requesting for the october-march visit?

Comment: I realise they're realted, but as per the [help], it's far better if you can split this into two posts. It's more likely to get answered. Putting on hold for now.

Comment: The middle question was there just to say. The important question is the main one. I've edited the question to only ask one thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Potentially.  The "Before you apply" section of the [eVisitor web site](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-#tab-content-0) sets out the potential consequences of applying for an eVisitor visa while another visa is in effect:

> **If you already hold another visa**
>
> If you already hold another visa and are then granted an eVisitor, the eVisitor could:
>
> - be valid as soon as it is granted
> - replace your existing visa.
>
> The eVisitor may be less beneficial than your current visa. If you already hold a visa, you should contact your nearest immigration office outside Australia before lodging an eVisitor application.

That is, if the application for the Temporary Activity visa happens to be approved before you are granted the eVisitor visa, you will lose the Temporary Activity visa.  Similarly, if you are granted the Temporary Activity visa while you are in Australia, then this visa (and the time limit) commences immediately.